# Фильтры в Angularjs

Tags: массивы, angularjs, search, filter

У меня есть некий json файл на сервере, методом get получаю с него данные. Нужно создать поиск по данным одного из массивов, с чем я справился так:

"filter:search" в ng-repeat, но в этом массиве содержится еще массив, как мне подключить к нему фильтр?
Пример json-файла:

```
"Organizations": { 
    "4374": { 
        "Name": "Магазин ИКЕА", 
        "Floors": [ 
            { "FloorID": 1, "Number": 1, "Type": null }, 
            { "FloorID": 20, "Number": 1, "Type": 0 } 
        ], 
    } 
}, 



<div ng-repeat="Organization in Organizations | toArray | filter:search">
```

так поиск осуществляется по имени и номеру.

Comment: пример входных и выходных данных может помочь понять, что ты хочешь сделать

Comment: Добавь все необходимое в сам вопрос. Отредактировать его можно с помощью кнопки [edit] под вопросом